# Checking a multiprocessing.Value's value after getting the lock

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

Here is a code snippet:

```
from multiprocessing import Value
import os

v = Value('i', 0)

# The following code runs in multiple processes
if v.value == 0:
    with v.get_lock():
        if v.value == 0: # Is this line necessary?
            v.value = os.getpid()
```

Since the `os.getpid()` varies, do I need to do another check after getting the lock?

I could imagine the following process flow without the additional check after getting the lock:

- P1 asks for the lock
- P2 asks for the lock
- P1 gets the lock and changes the value
- P1 releases the lock
- P2 gets the lock and changes the value
- P2 releases the lock

The value will then be the one set by P2, even though P1 got the lock and changed it first.

Am I wrong about the asumptions I am making? Does adding an additional check after getting the lock fix the problem in every case? If so, is it considered a good practice?

Comment: I haven't used shared memory objects with multiprocessing but there is absolutely a race condition between `if v.value == 0` and `with v.get_lock()`. So yes you would need to test again. More importantly maybe - [as it says in the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes), you probably don't want to be sharing memory unless it is a carefully considered decision. Now you have processes waiting on each other which may kill the main benefit of multiprocessing.

Comment: Perfect it answers my question. As for the use of multiprocessing, it is actually necessary in my project. All the processes are rushing to set the value, and they then work on their own for 10 to 30 minutes. I can't set the value *before* starting the processes and then pass it to all of them as an argument, because of the restrictions set by the framework I am using. Don't hesitate to write an answer!

Comment: Interesting situation! Thanks for explaining. What are the other processes doing in the meantime? When does the `Value` get set to `0` and who does that setting?

Comment: I just have a bunch of tasks that need to be executed, but I don't manage the execution (since the framework I'm using does). They all try to change the shared value if it is set to 0. But they also might not even be executed at the same time. It depends on a lot of things, but a case where they all try to change the value at the same time is likely to happen. As for the default value (0), it is set on the first instanciation of `v = Value('i', 0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used shared memory objects with multiprocessing but there is absolutely a [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) between `if v.value == 0` and `with v.get_lock()`.

So yes you would need to test again.

More importantly maybe - [as it says in the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes), you (or whoever reads this later) probably don't want to be sharing memory unless it is a carefully considered decision. Now you have processes waiting on each other which may kill the main benefit of multiprocessing.